# Mysql python connector is unavailable when running pip install --allow external

Tags: python, mysql, docker, python-3.4

While using Python 3.4 in a docker container, I have been using `pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python` to install the dependency on new containers. Suddenly, however, the command fails saying "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement". I checked pypi and the dependency is still there, but for some reason pip can't find it (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/2.0.4).

Any ideas why it no longer is able to see mysql-connector-python version 2.0.4 anymore and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

"With PEP 470 now requiring files to be hosted on PyPI, you may have noticed that MySQL Connector/Python is now no longer available using the pip-tool." 
...
"For now we suggest to download the latest Connector/Python directly from the MySQL homepage"

See https://geert.vanderkelen.org/2016/cpy-and-pypi/